# Laravel5.4 + Angular4

Tags: angular, laravel-5

Now I have an existing Angular2 project.
And I'm going to build the back-end for it by using laravel(v5.4).

The thing is I'm going to embed angular project into laravel.
Someone says, no need to embed cause of both of them are completely independent.

I have no clue which the best choice is...

If it is recommended to embed into laravel, how can I do it?

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Restful API is the best approach

Comment: Assume that NodeJs is used for back-end. Which is the best choice then?

Comment: Yea, but honestly i never really into php, but looking to some article they always used rest approach

Comment: Rest is the way to go here what @ShiftN'Tab suggested. Seperate your application in layers.